# AWS Glue Incremental crawl of continually arriving data on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm looking for a way to set-up an incremental Glue crawler for S3 data, where data arrives continuously and is partitioned by the date it was captured (so the S3 paths within the include path contain *date=yyyy-mm-dd*). My concern is, that if I run the crawler in the course of a day, the partition for it will be created, and will not be re-visited in subsequent crawls. Is there a way to force a given partition, that I know might still be receiving updates, to be crawled while running the crawler incrementally and not wasting resources on historic data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crawler will visit only new folders with an incremental crawl (assuming you have set *crawl new folders only* option). The only circumstance where adding more data to an existing folder would cause a problem is if you were changing schema by adding a differently formatted file into a folder that was already crawled. Otherwise the crawler has created the partition and knows the schema, and is ready to pull the data, even if new files are added to the existing folder.

Comment: The problem is that in some cases I want the data that were added to the existing folder to be crawled. I tried to delete the most recent partition and it isn't getting visited.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the answer: Once Glue has added a folder as an Athena partition, possibly updating the schema, Athena will consider whatever is in it at the time of the query, and Glue needn't run again just for Athena to consider fresh files that were not present in the folder at the time Glue added it.

Comment: So the crawler is defining the schema when it runs. Athena is getting the data when it runs. As long as you haven't changed the schema within a folder, running the crawler just once to recognize the schema and partition should be sufficient. Long story short, the crawler defines the schema and partitions, that schema is used later by Athena (or a glue job) to understand how to pull the data.